# Moving "pointer" to change the current debugging location

Tags: android-studio

When I debug, sometimes it's useful to repeat or skip certain code. In Visual Studio, you can move the default yellow arrow and you can repeat the code, skip some statements - [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx#Move%20the%20pointer%20to%20change%20the%20execution%20flow). Is such a thing possible in Android Studio ? I can't really see a way how to do it but maybe it's just not intuitive enough for me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint, by clicking the row on the left, next to the line number. Afterwards, run it in debug mode, and when the code execute to the breakpoint, the debug console will appear at the bottom.

Comment: thanks for reply however that's not what I look for. I know I can do that but many times, it's useful to repeat the executed steps.